# https request to my webAPI via ionic app return Error 403

Tags: android, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, ionic-framework

I have developed a small webapp using the ionic framework, which makes calls to a webAPI published to my server.

Up till now I did not have any SSL certification installed for the webAPI and have only been making "http" calls using the angular $http(request) method. I have recently purchased a certificate and have installed it and now I'm trying to make "https" calls instead.

- When emulating the app inside the chrome emulator the requests to MY API work as they should.
- BUT when making the same calls while testing the app on my android device, the requests returns : "403 (Forbidden ( The server denied the specified Uniform Resource Locator (URL). Contact the server administrator.))"

I have no idea why this is happening and any help in resolving this matter will be great!

Comment: I am having the same issue, even without HTTPS

Comment: @SenTaiyou I have the same problem... any resolution related that problem?